# Adjust free space in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel that contains a Label and a ComboBox:

```
var lblDesignGroup = new Label
{
    Name = "lblDesignGroup",
    Text = "DesignGroup",
    Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 0, 0)
};
tlpCallLog.Controls.Add(lblDesignGroup, 0, 0);

var cboDesignGroup = new ComboBox
{
    Name = "cboDesignGroup",
    DataSource = designGroups,
    DisplayMember = "DesignGroupName",
    ValueMember = "DesignGroupId",
    Margin = new Padding(0, 50, 0, 0),
    DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
};
```

Once I create them, I setup the TableLayoutPanel as:

```
tlpCallLog.ColumnStyles.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < tlpCallLog.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    tlpCallLog.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
}

tlpCallLog.RowStyles.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < tlpCallLog.RowCount; i++)
{
    tlpCallLog.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
}
tlpCallLog.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
```

[image]

But for some reason, I have blank space between the Label and the DropDown.
As you can see, the DropDown width adjusts correctly, it does not have any free space, but the Label has it.
I want to remove that space. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Label Control auto-sizes in a default layout (when child of a Form, as a standard scenario, since the Form performs its layout when initialized). When created like this, the AutoSize property is set to `true` because that's the default value, but the Layout is never performed.
When you explicitly set `AutoSize = true`, then the layout is performed.

Set both the TableLayoutPanel and the Label to AutoSize:

```
tlpCallLog.AutoSize = true;
tlpCallLog.RowStyles.Clear();
//[...]

var lblDesignGroup = new Label {
    AutoSize = true,
    Name = "lblDesignGroup",
    Text = "DesignGroup",
    Margin = new Padding(0, 53, 0, 0)
};
tlpCallLog.Controls.Add(lblDesignGroup, 0, 0);

var cboDesignGroup = new ComboBox {  
    //[...]
}
```

I suggest to set the Label's `Margin = new Padding(0, 53, 0, 0)`: 3 pixels down, to align with the ComboBox text. It's a valid measure with (almost) any Font size.

Another suggestion is to set the `[Form].AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi`.

[image: TableLayoutPanel AutoSize]

Comment: Set the Form's AutoScaleMode and TLP's AutoSize in the designer. The `Form.AutoScaleMode` is *suggested*, since two controls can inherit the Font in different ways. `TableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true` is instead mandatory. Otherwise, the TLP won't adapt to the size of the child controls. If you have other controls in there, you need to state that clearly.

Comment: Works! Thankyou!