# How to adjust Label and Combox so that both texts on the same baseline?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, controls

**Hello**

I want to create a Label and a ComboBox at runtime.

**How do I calculate Label.Top relative to ComboBox.Top so that the text of the two controls lie on one line?**

It should work for different fonts and border styles. The same Top and Height values for both controls don't do the Trick.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Test this: [Adjust free space in a TableLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492191/7444103), see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

The text-baseline calculations require using GetTextMetrics Api:

[gettextmetrics (gdi32)](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.gettextmetrics)

[GetTextMetrics function (wingdi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-gettextmetrics)

[image]

I'm more comfortable with VB.net :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Module Font_Metrics
    Public Structure FontMetrics
        Dim Ascent As Integer
        Dim Descent As Integer
        Dim Height As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Function GetMetrics(gfx As Graphics, fnt As Font) As FontMetrics
        Dim Hdc As IntPtr = gfx.GetHdc()
        Dim Hfont As IntPtr = fnt.ToHfont()
        Dim Metric As TEXTMETRIC
        Dim HfontDefault As IntPtr = SelectObject(Hdc, Hfont)
        GetTextMetrics(Hdc, Metric)
        SelectObject(Hdc, HfontDefault)
        DeleteObject(Hfont)
        gfx.ReleaseHdc(Hdc)

        Dim fm As FontMetrics
        fm.Ascent = Metric.tmAscent
        fm.Descent = Metric.tmDescent
        fm.Height = Metric.tmHeight
        Return fm
    End Function

    Private Structure TEXTMETRIC
        Dim tmHeight As Integer
        Dim tmAscent As Integer
        Dim tmDescent As Integer
        Dim tmInternalLeading As Integer
        Dim tmExternalLeading As Integer
        Dim tmAveCharWidth As Integer
        Dim tmMaxCharWidth As Integer
        Dim tmWeight As Integer
        Dim tmOverhang As Integer
        Dim tmDigitizedAspectX As Integer
        Dim tmDigitizedAspectY As Integer
        Dim tmFirstChar As Char
        Dim tmLastChar As Char
        Dim tmDefaultChar As Char
        Dim tmBreakChar As Char
        Dim tmItalic As Byte
        Dim tmUnderlined As Byte
        Dim tmStruckOut As Byte
        Dim tmPitchAndFamily As Byte
        Dim tmCharSet As Byte
    End Structure

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Function SelectObject(hdc As IntPtr, hgdiobj As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Function GetTextMetrics(hdc As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef lptm As TEXTMETRIC) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Function DeleteObject(hdc As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

End Module
```

Now you can calculate the text-baseline of combobox and align the top of label according to it:

```
Dim combo_fm As FontMetrics = GetMetrics(CreateGraphics, ComboBox.Font)
Dim label_fm As FontMetrics = GetMetrics(CreateGraphics, Label.Font)
SuspendLayout()
Label.Left = ComboBox.Left - Label.Width 
Dim BaseLine_y As Integer = ComboBox.Top + (ComboBox.Height - ComboBox.ItemHeight) / 2 + combo_fm.Ascent
Label.Top = BaseLine_y - Label.Padding.Top - label_fm.Ascent
ResumeLayout()
```

Comment: To get the Font's Cell Ascent and Descent values, you just need to call `[FontFamily].GetCellAscent()` and `GetCellDescent()` methods, passing the current Font style. Since the two Controls use the same Font, the value is always the same. What changes is the size of their Client Area...

Comment: @Jimi: I was not aware of getcell... methods and did this in hard way. Also I thought label and combo have different font family/size/styles.